# бесконечная загрузка ютуб плеера в андроид студио(апи ютуба)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, youtube-api

я написал простое приложение в андроид студио, которое по задумке при открытие должно запускать видео в ютубе,
воспользовался апи ютуба, но при запуске, открывается плеер юутуба и запускается якобы загрузка видео, но дело в том что эта загрузка бесконечная, я пробовал обновлять ютуб до последней версии но ничего не помогло
дебагер показал что по коду проблем нет, логкат ошибок не выдаёт никаких, приложение не вылетает, только бесконечная загрузка видео
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/25FDc.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZpjH.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHlVt.jpg
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b98o0.jpg

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.cezahuyna;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;


public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity {
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.YoutubePlayerView);

    onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo("LCDoHHh2HFo&t");
           //youTubePlayer.play();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    };

    youTubePlayerView.initialize("AIzaSyBook9p0MRPYNvdV9gwUwn339weWJ_IRRs", onInitializedListener);
}
}
```

build gradle is here:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
compileSdk 32

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.cezahuyna"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner 
"androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {

implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.4.0'
}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.cezahuyna">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


<queries>
    <intent>
        <action 
android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START" />
    </intent>
</queries>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.CeZaHuyna"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" 
/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: спасибо за поправление касательно языка, я новый пользователь и только начинаю разбираться с этим форумом

Comment: Если нужно показать код -- прикрепи его не как фото, а как текст, чтобы можно было скопировать и повторить.

Comment: ок, спасибо, сейчас сделаю

Comment: а что ты используешь в `loadVideo`? Я предполагаю что ты взял не тот айдишник видео, либо оно не признает значок амперсанта. Поставь просто `LCDoHHh2HFo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `youTubePlayer.loadVideo();` вы передаете строку, содержащую `&`, вам нужно поместить туда просто video id. К примеру `youTubePlayer.loadVideo("LCDoHHh2HFo");`

---

Так же рекомендую использовать библиотеку [android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player), поскольку стандартная от гугла не обновляется уже несколько лет и требует API key.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, несколько дней думал как решить проблему. Ваш ответ помог решить мне проблему